# Community Wikis

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Just a quick question: It seems that we are marking quite a lot of stuff as community wiki. Apparently you earn no rep from community wiki answers, which raises the question of whether it is a good idea to be using CW so much this early. Is this intentional? If so, is this such a good idea while we still have so few users with enough rep to vote to close/open and edit questions?

Comment: I was going to ask the same question, maybe we need a policy regarding when a question should be a CW and when it shouldn't. Take a look at this also:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question

Comment: An example of a question which I think shouldn't be a CW: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/700/a-conjecture-about-the-power-of-non-deterministic-turing-machines (probably made CW because of down votes.)

Comment: I think that question became a CW because of the large number of edits.

Comment: @ András Salamon: I see, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to propose the following FAQ statement about CW.

> The CW flag should be reserved for
>   questions where you do not believe
>   that there exists one (or even a few)
>   good answers, and where any individual
>   response contributes a small enough
>   piece of the overall answer that no
>   reputation increase is warranted.
>
> CW IS IRREVERSIBLE. When in doubt, DO
>   NOT mark a question CW - this can
>   always be changed later.
>
> Often, a question that seems like it
>   should be CW can be modified to be
>   more direct and focused, thus avoiding
>   the need for the tag. For example, the
>   seemingly CW question "What are the
>   key papers in topic X" can often be
>   reworded as the more focused "What I
>   should start reading when studying
>   topic X". The latter has one or a few
>   definite answers and need not be made
>   CW.

Since this answer will probably need editing, I'm marking it editable.

Comment: I think the tone of this statement might send the wrong message. There is nothing wrong with CW as such, and there are situations in which one *should* use CW.

Comment: I like this; having more advice for how to properly form a good question should be a focus of the meta-community (by which I mean the smaller community of people who are actively interested in how the community is shaped), and simple examples are probably the best guide.

Comment: @jukka in principle you are right. But it's clear that people are willing to ask a cw question even when there's a perfectly decent regular question buried underneath. 

This is the practice this would deal with. Like it or not, rep is the grease that makes the overall system work - witness our struggles getting hi-rep users - and we want to encourage people to use that system, by asking precise questions that encourage a few (or one) clear answers

Comment: here's another example of a question that I think should not have been made CW: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/832/space-time-tradeoff-lower-bounds

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments, I agree that the best solution would be to ask questions that don't need to be CW. I was just trying to point out that occasionally there are questions that really *should* be CW, and our FAQ shouldn't scare away people who'd like to ask those questions, either. Perhaps we could tone down the "CW IS IRREVERSIBLE" part, maybe not all-caps?-)

Comment: sure. go ahead and edit that !

Answer (score 3):

IMO, we're doing a reasonable job here.  The problem about having too few users with power will be resolved soon when we have moderators who will act in the community's interest.

*Reputation should be a signal of someone who an expert*.  Allowing too many open-ended questions could dilute the meaning of reputation on the site.

That being said, I think that many questions which are asked and are totally open-ended, could easily be rephrased in such a way as to be considered a valid question.  Putting some research into the question helps, backed by some specifics.

Comment: I agree, I think we are doing fairly well regarding tagging questions as CW vs. non-CW. Perhaps we have too many CW questions, but it is not because people mark too many questions as CW; it is because people ask many questions that *are* open-ended and should be marked as CW.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to see what other people's thoughts were. I haven't used stackoverflow, so still haven't quite figured out the community wikis. Actually I had the "Learning quantum CS" question in mind.

Comment: My feeling was that the learning quantum CS question did not need to be CW. But it was too late to do something about it.

Comment: I agree about that one, but this question was what I had in mind: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/811/what-are-the-classic-papers-from-the-recursion-theoretic-area-of-complexity-theor.

Comment: I should point out that the cw tag is irreversible, even by moderators

Comment: Yes, I think we should make a feature request that moderators should be able to reverse it...